# Delegate methods not called in implementation of NSURLSessionData

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I have a class, `AWSUtil`, and I would like to be able to get the progress of image uploads and downloads using `NSURLSessions`

```
class AWSUtil : NSObject, NSURLSessionDelegate, NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate
```

I'm able to set up the sessions, and they work

```
func sessionTest(url: NSURL){
    let task = NSURLSession(
        configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration(),
        delegate: self,
        delegateQueue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()
    ).dataTaskWithURL(url){(data, response, error) in
        //code   
    }

    task!.resume()
}
```

But my problem is that the delegate methods, such as `NSURLSession didWriteData` are not being called.

```
func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask, didWriteData bytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToWrite: Int64){
    //never called
}
```

I've tried implementing different `NSURLSession` protocols and making the class not conform to `NSObject`, but neither work. No matter what delegates I implement, or what delegate methods I put in the class, none of them are called.

I would assume it's because the object is being deallocated before they are called, but I'm not sure. If I wanted to make a call on one of the functions, I would use

```
func awsTest(url: NSURL){
    let aws = AWSUtil()
    aws.sessionTest(url)
}
```

But none of the `NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate` methods are being called. Is there any way to fix this, or is there a workaround?

Comment: `didWriteData` is a delegate method of `NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate` not `NSURLSessionDataDelegate`.

Comment: @0x141E The same thing happens with all delegate methods, even when I implement `NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate`. I clarified that in the question

Comment: Add a `deinit` method, and set a breakpoint on it. That way you'll know if your object is being released.

Comment: Have you tried not providing a completion handler? I think it either calls the delegate methods OR the completion handler.

Comment: @luk2302 I had to do that too to fix the problem. You may want to post an answer with that. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `dataTaskWithURL`. This is a data task method. Data tasks have a protocol called `NSURLSessionDataDelegate`. Override those methods, e.g. `URLSession:dataTask:...`.

`didWriteData` is called when using download methods, such as downloadTaskWithURL:, and you're not calling a download method.

If you look at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURLSession/downloadTaskWithURL:, in the contents area on the left you'll see that data, download, and upload tasks are broken out separately. Each has their corresponding delegate methods.

Comment: Thanks! the problem was that I was using `dataTaskWithURL` instead of `downloadTaskWithURL`. Also, I had to remove the completion handler from the call.